# Height of a conductor ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

We say an extension of Noetherian rings $R\subset S$ is elementary subintegral if $S=R[b]$ for some $b\in S$ with $b^2,b^3\in R$. The conductor ideal is defined to be $\operatorname{Ann}_R(S/R)$. What information does this conductor ideal provide?. Is the height of conductor ideal always at most 1?.
Can one produce a subintegral extension  with $S$ being polynomial algebra over a field and height of conductor greater than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R=k[x,xy,y^2,y^3]$ and $b=y$. Then $S=k[x,y]$ and $S/R$ is isomorphic to $R$ modulo the maximal ideal $(x,xy,y^2,y^3)$ which has height two.

Comment: I wonder if there's a counterexample with $R$ Cohen-Macaulay (or Gorenstein, if I want to be more greedy ...) ?

Comment: @Alex If both $R,S$ satisfy Serre condition $S_2$ ( weaker than locally Cohen- Macaulay) the height of the conductor ideal is one.

Comment: that's interesting to know ... do you have a reference or could you please sketch a proof? Thanks...

Comment: @Alex It is easy. Just use the fact that if you have $M\subset N$ of modules of depth at least two, then $N/M$ has depth at least one.

Comment: Agh gotcha, Thanks...although I would be using that $S$ is $(S_2)$ as an $R$-module ... not sure if the same holds if you assume $S$ is $(S_2)$ as a ring ...

Comment: And also, I think, $S$ satisfying $(S_1)$ as an $R$-module and $R$ satisfying $(S_2)$ is enough (just by depth lemma)

Comment: Sir, we can similarly do come up with an elementary sub integral extension whose conductor has height n by taking S polynomial algebra in n variables and R to generated by variables leaving out one, two product of all the variables and square and the cube of the left out one. Although the conductor of $k[x^2,x^3,y]\subset k[x,y]$ has height one, introducing $xy$ is increasing the height. What exactly is happening here?. Can we increase the height of conductor for affine algebras over a field similarly?

Comment: @Varadharajan Yes. Take $R=k[x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, x_1x_n, x_2x_n, \ldots, x_{n-1}x_n, x_n^2, x_n^3]$ and $b=x_n$.